# How to loop into nodes with same name

Tags: c++, boost, tree

I have a part of an XML with the following data :

```
           <DATA>
              <VALUE>July</VALUE>
              <VALUE>August</VALUE>
           </DATA>
```

In the following code, "kv.first()" is equal to "DATA"

```
BOOST_FOREACH(const boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &kv, children)
{
    std::cout << "kv.first : " << kv.first << std::endl;
    std::cout << "kv.second.data : " << kv.second.data() << std::endl;
}
```

And what I see with the std::cout is :

```
kv.first : DATA
kv.second.data : July
```

What I expect is rather :

```
kv.first : DATA
kv.second.data : July
kv.first : DATA
kv.second.data : August
```

Did I write something wrong ? Or something is missing ?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your BOOST::FOREACH loop to include the root tag:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("DATA"))
```

where **pt** is your **ptree**
If your root tag has some values before that you need to include them as well for example:

```
 <ROOT>
   <DATA>
      <VALUE>July</VALUE>
      <VALUE>August</VALUE>
   </DATA>
 </ROOT>
```

Now foreach loop becomes:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("ROOT.DATA"))
```